# Require AngularJs controller with webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am trying to use webpack with angularjs but can't make my controller work, when I try to require it and run it getting this error: `__webpack_require__(...) is not a function`. Below is my app.js and controller code:

```
//app.js
var angular = require('angular');
var weatherModule = angular.module('weather', []);

require('./shared/directives/app.directives')(weatherModule);
require('./weather/weather.controller')(weatherModule);

//weather.controller.js
module.export = function(weatherModule) {
    weatherModule.controller('WeatherCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.greetings = 'Hey from controller';
    }]);
}
```

If I directly write controller code in app.js itself that works fine like: `weatherModule.controller('WeatherCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){}])`

Answer (score 0):

This was typo mistake, it should have been `module.exports` instead of `export`